# Wrong number of Arguments error in Net::HTTP.get call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, net-http

I am trying a simple get call in Rails 5.2 application as follows.

```
   uri = URI("https://www.google.co.in")

   req = Net::HTTP::get(uri)
```

It gives following error.

1: from (irb):85:in `rescue in irb_binding'
**ArgumentError (Failed to open TCP connection to [www.google.co.in:443](http://www.google.co.in:443) (wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)))**

Note : Same code works in Rails 3 application. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post a longer stack trace and your ruby version? There is nothing technically wrong with the code you posted and `Net::HTTP` is a standard ruby library so I am not sure what impact rails is having on this

Comment: @engineersmnky the tags on this show `ruby-2.6.5`.  But without context, and full stack trace we can't find anything wrong with those 2 lines of code.

Comment: @lacostenycoder true but I'd prefer the version be in the post since the tags are horribly abused. I have seen posts tagged with 3 rails versions at the same time